# Image slicing with SVG images not working on Xcode12

Tags: ios, svg, xcode12

Xcode 12 just introduced SVG image support and I've been using them without major problems, however when I tried image slicing the chat bubbles so they stretch correctly depending on the number of characters in the text message, it doesn't seem to work, can't find anything on stackoverflow or apple forum yet so just wondering if anyone knows if it is a known issue or Xcode 12 bug?

This is the chat bubble SVG:

```
<svg width="206" height="80" viewBox="0 0 206 80" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="20.4998" y="16" width="161.484" height="40" rx="20" fill="lightseagreen"/>
<path d="M186 56C175.984 56 169.984 55 169.984 46H177.984C177.984 50.0156 176.984 52 186 56Z" fill="lightseagreen"/>
</svg>
```

How it looks in Xcode assets:

[image]

When I click 'Show slicing' here's how it looks:

[image]

Compare to the usual 'Show slicing' of PNG images which are working fine:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: My Xcode crashes every time when I enter different values for the horizontal/vertical slicing and click on "Show slicing". Pretty sure this was not tested with SVGs.